# How to catch custom raised exceptions from oracle to java

Tags: java, reactjs, oracle, exception, error-handling

I have an oracle db which has a trigger on a table. It raises a custom exception on delete if some conditions are met. In Java I use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in my DAO layer. Structure is classical controller-service-dao. How do I catch the text of this exception in Java? Thanks in advance.
This is my trigger.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "ME"."EDITABLE_SETTINGS_DELETE" 
BEFORE DELETE ON "ME"."MAP_SETTINGS"
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
CURSOR is_editable_cursor IS
select is_editable
from map_calculation mc 
inner join map_calculation_group mg on mc.id_calc = mg.id_calc
where mg.id_calc = mc.id_calc and mg.id_settings = :old.id_settings;
TYPE is_editable_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1 CHAR);
v_is_editable is_editable_table;
BEGIN
OPEN is_editable_cursor;
FETCH is_editable_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO v_is_editable;
CLOSE is_editable_cursor;
IF ('F' MEMBER OF v_is_editable) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20017, 'You cannot delete settings inn an uneditable calculation' );
END IF;
COMMIT;
END;
```

This is the dao impl

```
@Override
    public void delete(Integer id) {
        SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("ID_SETTINGS", id);
        try {
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(DELETE_SQL, parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Error during deletion: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This is the react front button

```
                        <Button
                            variant='primary'
                            onClick={() => {
                                globalProps
                                    .deleteItem()
                                    .then(() => {
                                        table.draw();
                                    })
                                    .catch((e) => {
                                        console.log(e);
                                        this.setState({ error: e.message });
                                        this.setState({ showModalBatch: true });
                                    });
                                this.props.toggleShowDelete();
                            }}
                        >
                            Удалить
                        </Button>
```

I have a modal which shows the message and what it shows is just "request failed with status code 500"

Comment: Can you show how you raise an exception in the database?

Comment: Why is it different to catching and handling any other exception?

Comment: custom raise exceptions in oracle normally use codes from -20001 to -20999. It should not be different to catch or handle any other exception.

Comment: I will edit with some code

Comment: Edited, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    ...
} catch (DataAccessException ex) {
    if (ex.getRootCause() instanceof SQLException) {
        SQLException sqlEx = (SQLException) ex.getRootCause();
        int errorCode = sqlEx.getErrorCode();
        if (errorCode == -20017) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it says I can't use SQLException because the statements inside try never throw one

Comment: Somehow there is no such rootcause because in this case i don't get any modal at all...